# ActiveMQ High Memory Usage

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am still working on a project that use ActiveMQ. In my case, I have about 20k-30k user that subscribe to unique queue in ActiveMQ. I realize that after 4-5 hours, ActiveMQ will consume almost 80-90% of my RAM and then crash. So I need to restart ActiveMQ every 3 or 4 hours to prevent ActiveMQ crash. Now I use levelDB as persistence adapter and it makes the restart process faster. My server has 6 core, 16GB RAM. Can someone kindly help me with a solution for this problem? :)